# Best way to refactor this code, if enums are not extensible

Tags: java, class, oop, enums, refactoring

Consider the following class that represent a entity and has method which return data of type **EnumA**

**EntityA** class:

```
public class EntityA
{   
    public Set<EnumA> getProcessedFlags() { ... }
}
```

**EnumA**:

```
public enum EnumA {
  READ_ONLY,
  READ_WRITE,
  PERMISSION_DENIED,
  COMMENT_ENABLED
}
```

Now I got the requirement to add one more **EntityB**, which is similar to **EntityA**, but logically different. (Same method signatures but different implementation:

There is one more thing, the return value which was **EnumA** in **EntityA**, is **EnumB for **EntityB**.

**EnumA** and **EnumB** are two different set, which represent a collection of logically same flags, but have some exclusive values in each of them:

**EnumB**

```
public enum EnumB {
  READ_ONLY,
  READ_WRITE,
  LIKE_ENABLED
}
```

So To refactor this, I made a abstract base class - **EntityBase**, and made both **EntityA** and **EntityB**, child of this base class.

Problem is **enums are not extensible**, Is there a good way to refactor this?

I thought of creating class structure something like this below:

```
public enum EnumBase {}

public enum EnumA extends EnumBase {}

public enum EnumB extends EnumBase {}

public abstract class EntityBase
{
  public Set<? extends EnumBase> getProcessedFlags();
}

public class EntityA extends EntityBase
{   
    public Set<EnumA> getProcessedFlags() { ... }
}

public class EntityB extends EntityBase
{   
    public Set<EnumB> getProcessedFlags() { ... }
}
```

Since Enums in java are not extensible, Can we have some better design to maintain this EntityBase class?

Comment: Thought about the possibility of using classes exclusively? i.e avoiding the Enums altogether? Also, since the flags are common to EntityA and EntityB, we can separate the flags from the Entities, only its combination needs to be kept track of, probably using a Set?

Also please note, Enums as a way to distinguish 'type' has a C/C++ flavor to it!

Comment: Main concern is this Enum is already getting used as Enum at many places. Separating out the entities and enums completely, is definitely a solution. But would it scale, with adding more similar entities and enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to offer specific advice without more context, but it's worth noting that enums can share interfaces, so you can try something like this:

```
interface Base {
    String name();
}

interface A extends Base {}
interface B extends Base {}

public enum EnumBase implements A, B {
    READ_ONLY,
    READ_WRITE
}

public enum EnumA implements A {
    PERMISSION_DENIED,
    COMMENT_ENABLED
}

public enum EnumB implements B {
    LIKE_ENABLED
}

public abstract class EntityBase<F extends Base> {
    public abstract Set<F> getProcessedFlags();
}

public class EntityA extends EntityBase<A> {
    @Override
    public Set<A> getProcessedFlags() { ... }
}

public class EntityB extends EntityBase<B> {
    @Override
    public Set<B> getProcessedFlags() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shmosel, Seems like a better and reasonable design. One major concern here I can see, that in case we add another Entity - EntityC with enum return type as EnumC, All other Enums need to be checked and restructured accordingly.

I am also amazed to check if there is some way of grouping enums.

One way I can think of is creating a final class having enums as its properties, but that too is not scalable and not readable too. 


`public final class PermissionFlags {
   enum EnumCommon {
    COMMON
   }
   enum EnumA {
    VAL1
  }

 enum EnumB {
    VAL1
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

A different solution would be to use one enum for all PermissionsFlags and then add an attribute that allows you to check if the PermissionFlag can be used with this class.

```
public enum PermissionFlag {
    READ_ONLY,
    READ_WRITE,
    PERMISSION_DENIED(EntityA.class),
    COMMENT_ENABLED(EntityA.class),
    LIKE_ENABLED(EntityB.class);

    private final Class<?> useForClass;

    PermissionFlag() {
        this(null);
    }

    PermissionFlag(Class<?> useForClass) {
        this.useForClass = useForClass;
    }

    /**
     * Check if given class can be used for this PermissionFlag.
     */
    public boolean useForClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return useForClass == null || useForClass.equals(clazz);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Stream consisting of all the PermissionFlags that can be used with the given class.
     */
    public static Stream<PermissionFlag> getPermissionsFlags(Class<?> clazz){
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(flag -> flag.useForClass(clazz));
    }
}
```

And then you can use `getPermissionFlags(EntityA.class).collect(Collectors.toList())` to get a List of all the Permissions flag for `EntityA`.